# Temp JSON data - Swift

Tags: json, swift, avkit

I am trying to create a temp JSON depending on whether a listener is tuned into a podcast or a radio station.

Because we already have all the podcast info we don't need to ask a remote JSON for it. But we still need to have the ability that when the MusicPlayer is playing that in the View it shows the cover, artist and title.

So my thinking was create a simple JSON Struct inside the MusicPlayer class and when the media player sends the data to the following

```
func getArtBoard(artist: String, song: String, cover: String) {
    
    
    guard let url = URL(string: cover) else { return }
    getData(from: url) { [weak self] image in
        guard let self = self,
            let downloadedImage = image else {
                return
        }
        let artwork = MPMediaItemArtwork.init(boundsSize: downloadedImage.size, requestHandler: { _ -> UIImage in
            return downloadedImage
        })
        self.nowplaying(with: artwork, artist: artist, song: song)
    }
}
```

It would also save it temp to - which is inside the

```
class MusicPlayer {
struct NowPlaying: Codable, Identifiable {
    var id: ObjectIdentifier
    var artist : String
    var song : String
    var cover : String
}
//more code here
}
```

However I am getting two errors

1. Type 'MusicPlayer.NowPlaying' does not conform to protocol 'Decodable'
2. Type 'MusicPlayer.NowPlaying' does not conform to protocol 'Encodable'

Questions:

1. How do I make it to conform. - But we able to call it via Music.NowPlaying.
2. Is this the best way to do it, or can I access the  `MPMediaItemPropertyTitle` in View?

The complete code.

```
import Foundation
import AVFoundation
import MediaPlayer
import AVKit

class MusicPlayer {
static let shared = MusicPlayer()
static var mediatype = ""
struct NowPlaying: Codable, Identifiable {
    var id: ObjectIdentifier
    var artist : String
    var song : String
    var cover : String
}



var player: AVPlayer?
let playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()

    
    func gettype(completion: @escaping (String) -> Void){
        
          completion(MusicPlayer.mediatype)
     
    }
    
    func getNowPlayingView(completion: @escaping (String) -> Void){
        
          completion(MusicPlayer.mediatype)
     
    }

    func startBackgroundMusic(url: String, type:String) {
        
        MusicPlayer.mediatype = String(type)
        
        //let urlString = "http://stream.radiomedia.com.au:8003/stream"
        let urlString = url
        guard let url = URL.init(string: urlString) else { return }

        let playerItem = AVPlayerItem.init(url: url)
        player = AVPlayer.init(playerItem: playerItem)
        
      
        do {

            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playback, mode: .default, options: [.duckOthers, .defaultToSpeaker, .mixWithOthers, .allowAirPlay])
            print("Playback OK")
           // let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
           // defaults.set("1", forKey: defaultsKeys.musicplayer_connected)
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
            print("Session is Active")
        } catch {
           // let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
          //  defaults.set("0", forKey: defaultsKeys.musicplayer_connected)
            print(error)
        }

         #if targetEnvironment(simulator)

        self.playerViewController.player = player
        self.playerViewController.player?.play()
        print("SIMULATOR")

         #else

        self.setupRemoteTransportControls()
        player?.play()

        #endif

    }
    
    
    func startBackgroundMusicTwo() {

        
        let urlString = "http://stream.radiomedia.com.au:8003/stream"
        //let urlString = url
        guard let url = URL.init(string: urlString) else { return }

        let playerItem = AVPlayerItem.init(url: url)
        player = AVPlayer.init(playerItem: playerItem)
        
      
        do {

            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playback, mode: .default, options: [.duckOthers, .defaultToSpeaker, .mixWithOthers, .allowAirPlay])
            print("Playback OK")
           // let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
           // defaults.set("1", forKey: defaultsKeys.musicplayer_connected)
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
            print("Session is Active")
        } catch {
           // let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
          //  defaults.set("0", forKey: defaultsKeys.musicplayer_connected)
            print(error)
        }

         #if targetEnvironment(simulator)

        self.playerViewController.player = player
        self.playerViewController.player?.play()
        print("SIMULATOR")

         #else

        self.setupRemoteTransportControls()
        player?.play()

        #endif

    }




func setupRemoteTransportControls() {
   // Get the shared MPRemoteCommandCenter
    let commandCenter = MPRemoteCommandCenter.shared()

    // Add handler for Play Command
    commandCenter.playCommand.addTarget { [unowned self] event in
        if self.player?.rate == 0.0 {
            self.player?.play()
            return .success
        }
        return .commandFailed
    }

    // Add handler for Pause Command
    commandCenter.pauseCommand.addTarget { [unowned self] event in
        if self.player?.rate == 1.0 {
            self.player?.pause()
            return .success
        }
        return .commandFailed
    }

   // self.nowplaying(artist: "Anna", song: "test")


}

func nowplaying(with artwork: MPMediaItemArtwork, artist: String, song: String){

MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.default().nowPlayingInfo = [
      MPMediaItemPropertyTitle:song,
      MPMediaItemPropertyArtist:artist,
      MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork: artwork,
      MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyIsLiveStream: true
]


   // self.getArtBoard();
}


func setupNowPlayingInfo(with artwork: MPMediaItemArtwork) {
      MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.default().nowPlayingInfo = [
        //   MPMediaItemPropertyTitle: "Some name",
        //   MPMediaItemPropertyArtist: "Some name",
           MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork: artwork,
           //MPMediaItemPropertyPlaybackDuration: CMTimeGetSeconds(currentItem.duration),
           //MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyPlaybackRate: 1,
           //MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyElapsedPlaybackTime: CMTimeGetSeconds(currentItem.currentTime())
       ]
   }



func getData(from url: URL, completion: @escaping (UIImage?) -> Void) {
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
        if let data = data {
            completion(UIImage(data:data))
        }
    })
        .resume()
}

func getArtBoard(artist: String, song: String, cover: String) {
    
    
    guard let url = URL(string: cover) else { return }
    getData(from: url) { [weak self] image in
        guard let self = self,
            let downloadedImage = image else {
                return
        }
        let artwork = MPMediaItemArtwork.init(boundsSize: downloadedImage.size, requestHandler: { _ -> UIImage in
            return downloadedImage
        })
        self.nowplaying(with: artwork, artist: artist, song: song)
    }
}



    func stopBackgroundMusic() {
        guard let player = player else { return }
        player.pause()

}
}
```

### Update

Got the above error solved thanks to the comment below.

However am having issues fetching the data.

```
Type 'MusicPlayer.NowPlayingData.Type' cannot conform to 'Encodable'; only struct/enum/class types can conform to protocols
```

The code I used. - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsonencoder

```
let encoder = JSONEncoder()
    encoder.outputFormatting = .prettyPrinted

    let data = try encoder.encode(NowPlayingData)
    print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!)
```

To write it I placed

```
func getArtBoard(artist: String, song: String, cover: String) {
    MusicPlayer.NowPlayingData(artist: artist, song: song, cover: cover)
}
```

DATA trying to encode

```
func getArtBoard(artist: String, song: String, cover: String) {
    //MusicPlayer.NowPlayingData(artist: artist, song: song, cover: cover)
    let pear = "{'artist':\(artist), 'song': \(song), 'cover':\(cover)}"
    let encoder = JSONEncoder()
    encoder.outputFormatting = .prettyPrinted
    MusicPlayer.JN = try encoder.encode(pear)
```

Comment: `ObjectIdentifier` doesn't conform, so the compiler cannot auto synthesize conformance. Does it need to be `ObjectIdentifier`? Are you getting the `id` from JSON or just creating on your own? If on your own, you could conform to `Identifiable` with other types, for example: `var id = UUID()`

Comment: @NewDev I’ll give that a try. I honestly don’t need id.

Comment: @NewDev Thanks that worked a treat - but ran into a small issue see updated.

Comment: `encoder.encode(actualNowPlayingDataObject)` - you're passing in a type, but need to pass the object you want to encode

Comment: @NewDev - I don't quite understand... Do I have to make a new actualNewPlayingDataObject?

Comment: I mean, you're trying to encode some object (of type `NowPlayingData`) with the actual data into JSON. What is that object that you're trying to encode?

Comment: @NewDev - My aim is to be able to show Now Playing information in a view. 

Sice all the data goes first to getArtBoard I need to store it inside MusicPlayer but then when I need to fetch the data I need a new func to fetch the data that got set by getArtBoard

Comment: I'm not fully following your code. If you need to fetch the data to populate some of of `NowPlaying` type, then why are you trying to use `.encode`, which encode things into JSON? Also, I just noticed - is this a typo? You have both `NowPlaying` and `NowPlayingData`

Comment: @NewDev see above added data that I am trying to encode but getting Cannot assign value of type 'Data' to type 'String'

Comment: It's really confusing what you're doing. What is `MusicPlayer.JN` supposed to be? How's the `getArtBoard` in the edit part of your question relate to the same function in the "complete code" section? It looks like this function gets the artwork, but then for some reason you're trying to encode something. I suggest you start a new question and reduce it as much as you can to just the relevant part

Comment: It stores the RAW now playing data